# What is the difference between using JQuery and Javascript to get elements by their ID?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm adding dynamic elements to an html form that I have for answer checking and figured for the sake of simpler and easier to read code, I'd get elements by ID using...

`$(' #id ');`

as opposed to...

`document.getElementByID(' id ');`

But I'm noticing that it won't pull the same information. When attempting to get the value of the input box, it always returns 'undefined' when using the JQuery method, but not when using Javascript. Here is a snippet of my code for context...

```
var validation = true;

function checkSubmit() {
  
    // Using Javascript method
    const firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
    const firstname_title = document.getElementById('firstname-title');

    if (firstname.value.length == 0) { // JQuery method doesn't return correct value here
        if (validation) {
            validation = false;
            firstname.style = "border-color: red;color: whitesmoke;transition: 0.25s;";
            firstname_title.style = "border-color: red;transition: 0.25s;";
            
            name_label = document.createElement('label');
              name_label.className = "d-flex justify-content-center fade-content-label";
              name_label.id = 'name-label';
              name_label.style = "color: red;font-size: 20px";
              name_label_node = document.createTextNode('Please enter a firstname');
              name_label.appendChild(name_label_node);
            var insert = $(' #name-insert '); // JQuery method works here
            insert.prepend(name_label);
        }
    }
}
```

I've ensured that my JQuery CDN libraries are up to date and that there aren't any conflicts with versions. Is there a fundamental difference between these two methods?

Comment: jQuery (the `$` function, usually) returns a jQuery object, not a DOM node reference. You can get the DOM node out of the jQuery object if you want. You can research jQuery via the *extensive* online documentation.

Comment: Remember jQuery always returns a collection, getElementByID just returns an Element.  JQuery does have a help method for `value`, it's `val()`..  So it's `firstname.val().length`  https://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Well, jQuery is a specific library with specific functionality.  Some of that functionality is *similar to* native DOM methods, but the two are not 100% compatible as drop-in replacements for one another.  Is there a specific example of an operation which isn't working as you expect?  What specifically "always returns undefined"?

Comment: Also there is no need for spaces around the selector strings in your jQuery calls. They don't hurt anything, but they look weird.

Comment: Difference is about 70,000 bytes. :) In this day in age I would not really learn jQuery unless your job/project is still using it.

Comment: `// JQuery method doesn't return correct value here` - but you haven't used jQuery in your code up to this point.